# Multiple replace in same line based on regex in vim

Tags: c, regex, vim, printf

What's the **regex** to change `"write" to "fprintf"` AND (the second comma) `","..."strlen"...")" to ""`?

for example,

```
write(fd_global,"Currently inside of main after the arguments are parsed\n", strlen("Currently inside of main after the arguments are parsed\n"));
```

to

```
fprintf(fd_global, "Currently inside of main after the arguments are parsed\n");
```

I know `"/write.*strlen"` matches each line with `"write"..."strlen"` but that's it.

Thanks in advance!

MY ANSWER
**:%s/write(/fprintf(/gc | %s/,\s*strlen((.*))/)/gc**

| for two separate search and replaces in same command
\s* for uncertain amount of whitespace between the second and third parameters of write

Comment: Your question is quite hard to understand -- try wrapping the code bits with the backtick `\`` to distinguish it from the text of your question. (Or read more about [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting))

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
%s/\v^write\((.*), strlen.*/fprintf(\1);/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion, for an expression which will replace `strlen` only when it occurs inside `write` and calls on the same string as you've written it here:

```
%s/write(\([^,]*\),\("[^"]*"\), strlen(\2))/fprintf(\1, \2)/gc
```